# Next and previous button using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-parsing

I am using a PHP `Simple HTML DOM Parser` to save a website as a `htm` file. I then use jQuery to extract a `div` from the file and put it into a `div`. I want to create a 
Previous and Next button but the problem I have is that to do this I have to change the URL so the parser can get the page. I would really appreciate if you can help. Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php 
    include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html=file_get_html( 'http://roosterteeth.com/home.php?page=1');
    $html->save('site/rtnews.htm')                      
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#wrap').click(function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#wrap").load('site/rtnews.htm #postsArea');    
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Next & Previous buttons for what purpose?

Comment: I am extracting posts from inside the 'htm' file. So I will use the Next & Previous button to change the page 'URL' used by the parser. So if I press next it will change the 'URl' to http://roosterteeth.com/home.php?page=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new php file for this and make an AJAX request to that file. I assume you have already realised that you cannot make a cross-domain request due to CORS.

Here is your new php file, let's call it `proxy.php`. It will proxy the request, responding with the page that is passed to it via GET :

```
<?php
  include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
  $html=file_get_html( 'http://roosterteeth.com/home.php?page=' . $_GET["page"]);
  echo $html;
?>
```

Your new JavaScript;

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
    page = 1;

  $('#next').on('click', function () {
    getPage(++page);
  });

  $('#prev').on('click', function () {
    getPage(--page);
  });

  var getPage = function (page) {
    $wrap.load('proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea');   
  };

  getPage(page);

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it but I am receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`. I'm not sure if there is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't worry I managed to get it to work using an updated jquery. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.